Logs for compression in gRPC APIs in Go Lang
I have enabled compression for a gRPC API, I want to verify if the response is getting compressed internally or not, Is there a way I can see the logs (trace logs) that the response is getting compressed?
I have used a custom unary interceptor but I am not able to see the logs.
func loggingUnaryInterceptor(ctx goContext.Context, logger *log.LogWrapper) grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    return func(
        ctx goContext.Context,
        req interface{},
        info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
        handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
    ) (interface{}, error) {
        start := time.Now()

        p, ok := peer.FromContext(ctx)
        if ok {
            logger.Infow(ctx, "Request received",
                zap.String("method", info.FullMethod),
                zap.String("peer", p.Addr.String()),
            )
        }

        md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
        if ok {
            enc := md.Get("grpc-encoding")
            if len(enc) > 0 {
                logger.Infow(ctx, "Request metadata", zap.String("compression", enc[0]))
            } else {
                logger.Infow(ctx, "Request metadata", zap.String("compression", "none"))
            }
        }

        resp, err := handler(ctx, req)

        duration := time.Since(start)
        logger.Infow(ctx, "Request handled",
            zap.String("method", info.FullMethod),
            zap.Duration("duration", duration),
            zap.String("peer", p.Addr.String()),
            zap.Error(err),
        )

        return resp, err
    }
}


The logs should provide more details and may include the compression.
